# Many-To-Many relationship in Google App Engine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, many-to-many

Is it possible to establish a Many-To-Many relationship between objects in Google App Engine?
I am a newbie in GAE and still reading about it. The coding seems quite different from the usual Java coding I am used to. I've read the Getting Started guestbook tutorial. So, can I get any help/tutorials/videos/knowledge from GAE users??
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About documentation this is a good start point:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html

Respect to many to many relationship from http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html :

> We can model a many-to-many relationship by maintaining collections of
>   keys on both sides of the relationship. Let's adjust our example to
>   let Food keep track of the people that consider it a favorite:

Person.java

```
import java.util.Set;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

// ...
    @Persistent
    private Set<Key> favoriteFoods;
```

Food.java

```
import java.util.Set;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

// ...
    @Persistent
    private Set<Key> foodFans;
```

> In this example, the Person maintains a Set of Key values that
>   uniquely identify the Food objects that are favorites, and the Food
>   maintains a Set of Key values that uniquely identify the Person
>   objects that consider it a favorite. When modeling a many-to-many
>   using Key values, be aware that it is the app's responsibility to
>   maintain both sides of the relationship:

Album.java

```
// ...
public void addFavoriteFood(Food food) {
    favoriteFoods.add(food.getKey());
    food.getFoodFans().add(getKey());
}

public void removeFavoriteFood(Food food) {
    favoriteFoods.remove(food.getKey());
    food.getFoodFans().remove(getKey());
}
```

Comment: thank you. I'm reading the doc! :)

Comment: knowning about j2ee turned out to be helpful!